# Rename "Report Type" label and name and migrate to Salesforce production instance

Tags: migration-tool

As a part of CI/CD pipelin we have following
1. A sandbox where we develop with a branch on bitbucket. 
2. A branch and a sandbox for QA.
3. A master branch for holding production box metadata.
4. A Production instance

So we develop on dev then push to dev branch from where it goes to qa and after review it gets pushed to master branch ...

We renamed certain custom report types label and name on dev sandbox. Same reports are in production.

We are using sourcetree/mavensmate/vscode as our tool for development.

My question here is - what entry should be made to package.xml and destructiveChangesPost.xml for renamed report types.

Screenshot of sourcetree

[image]

It shows as "R". How should I handle this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. I would recommend you to edit your question. The CI/CD, pipeline, branches, etc. is not at all relevant in your question. Your question basically is about what should be in your package.xml and destructiveChanges.xml. Please take a moment and refer [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) on this forum and also have you referred to the documentation as what needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you are to deploy this to production, you **might** need to delete the original record types first. On the destructive changes file, you'll write the names of those record types that were renamed, so that the tool can wipe them before deploying the new ones.

After deleting the old ones, you will just deploy the new ones normally.

---

> I'm saying that you **might** need to delete the original ones first. But this might not be true, you can try to deploy the modified ones before deleting the old ones.

---

As to what to write on the package.xml file, you can refer to the Ant Migration Tool Guide to see how to [deploy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool_deploy.htm) and how to [delete files from an org](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/daas_destructive_changes.htm).